# What can cause a BadTimeout in OpcUa?

Tags: qt, opc-ua, qtopcua

I have a Qt application that exchange data via QtOpcUa.
I don't have any polling or browsing or other operation but a bunch of subscriptions.
Every few minutes I get a `BadTimeout` error from the server that closes the connection.

This happens only if I have any subscription enabled *and* more than one PLC connected.
But what can cause such a timeout?

[Here](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdknet/2.5.7/html/classUnifiedAutomation_1_1UaBase_1_1StatusCodes.html#aecaa80fbfaca19a6c4935b8d184a9ca5) I read:

> The operation timed out.

How a subscription can "time out"? It's done by the server itself! Is it a problem of the server or can I do anything client side?

The messages I receive are:

```
[20231003 12:51:19 I] unknown:0 - "Received a ServiceFault response"
[20231003 12:51:19 I] unknown:0 - "The ServiceResult has the StatusCode BadTimeout"
[20231003 12:51:19 W] unknown:0 - "Received Timeout for Publish Response"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client application may be sending/queueing more PublishRequests than the activity level of the Subscriptions needs, or with timeout hints in the RequestHeader that are too short, and eventually the server de-queues it and finds that it was received longer ago than the timeout hint and sends back a ServiceFault response with Bad_Timeout.

Comment: Can you please explain what is "activity level of the subscription"? Is it related to the rate of change of the variables?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. If MonitoredItems are not queueing change notifications, the Subscription will only de-queue and use a PublishRequest when it needs to send a Keep Alive Notification.

Comment: No matter which settings I use in [Matrikon OPC UA Explorer](https://www.matrikonopc.com/opc-ua/products/opc-ua-explorer.aspx), it holds the connection. Instead, no matter which settings I use in my QtOpcUa application, I get the error. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: For "settings" I mean MaxKeepAliveCount and LifetimeCount

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know anything about QtOpcUa or its implementation.